How can I correctly inherit and extend the POS template in Odoo 17?
I am tying to inherit a template in point_of_sale screen so that i can change the function the "Invoice" button is targeting. Here is the template i am trying to inherit
<templates id="template" xml:space="preserve">
        <t t-name="point_of_sale.PaymentScreenButtons">
        <div class="payment-buttons d-flex flex-column flex-wrap">
            <button class="button js_invoice btn btn-light py-3 text-start rounded-0 border-bottom" t-att-class="{ 'highlight text-bg-primary': currentOrder.is_to_invoice() }"
                t-on-click="toggleIsToInvoice">
                <i class="fa fa-file-text-o me-2" />Invoice
            </button>
        </div>
    </t>

</templates>

Here’s a snippet of my XML code
<odoo>
    <template id="extend_payment_screen_buttons" inherit_id="point_of_sale.template">
        <xpath expr="//button[contains(@class, 'js_invoice')]" position="replace">
            <button class="button js_invoice btn btn-light py-3 text-start rounded-0 border-bottom"
                    t-att-class="{ 'highlight text-bg-primary': currentOrder.is_to_invoice() }"
                    t-on-click="createAndPrintInvoice">
                <i class="fa fa-file-text-o me-2"/>Invoice
            </button>
        </xpath>
    </template>
 </odoo>

The error i am getting is:
ValueError: External ID not found in the system: point_of_sale.template
Can Someone help?
I tried changing the ID but still nothing.

Try exending it by the name, in your xml template file...
<templates xml:space="preserve">

    <t t-name="my_module.PaymentScreenButtons" t-inherit="point_of_sale.PaymentScreenButtons" t-inherit-mode="extension" owl="1">
           <xpath expr="//button[hasClass('js_invoice')]" position="replace">
               <button class="button js_invoice btn btn-light py-3 text-start rounded-0 border-bottom"
                    t-att-class="{ 'highlight text-bg-primary': currentOrder.is_to_invoice() }"
                    t-on-click="createAndPrintInvoice">
                <i class="fa fa-file-text-o me-2"/>Invoice
            </button>
    
           </xpath>
       </t>
</templates>

The createAndPrintInvoice function and currentOrder must exist in the payment_screen.js otherwise you must patch the script and create them to be able to use them.
You can check the official documentation for more details
